# How to get rid of the annoying characters in `tmux` panes and menus

Tags: terminal, tmux, putty

I noticed that in several places in the tmux panes and menus, there are chartacters being displayed in the boundaries.
Example 1:
[image: Example 1]

Example 2:
[image]

How do I get rid of these characters and make them solid colored boundaries with nothing in them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are ACS line drawing characters. Putty does not support ACS line drawing in UTF-8 mode. For this reason (since tmux 1.4) tmux uses UTF-8 line drawing characters when UTF-8 is enabled. Make sure tmux knows the terminal supports UTF-8, either by using the `-u` flag (`tmux -u new` and `tmux -u attach`) or by setting `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` appropriately.

Alternatively, you may be able to configure Putty to disable its UTF-8 support, but I don't know how to do this.